# "application: not a procedure" Everything works except my attempt to print a #t

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to print a basic #t. #f does print, but as soon as I try #t to be printed I just get an error. It happens when you get an empty list, which is usually when it's on the leave/child nodes.

Program checks if the input is a binary tree or not.

Arbol means tree.

```
(define (arbol-binario? a)
  (if (list? a) 
      (if (null? a)
          #t
          (if (= (length a) 3)
              ((arbol-binario? (second a))
               (arbol-binario? (cdr (cdr a))))
              #f))
      #f))
```

Comment: `((if ` look there, both times

Comment: fixed the format. Still the same problem though. Scheme is full of parenthesis I get confused alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```
((arbol-binario? (second a))
 (arbol-binario? (cdr (cdr a))))
```

If `(arbol-binario? (second a))` evaluates to `#t` then 
the application is: `(#t (arbol-binario? (cdr (cdr a)))` and you will get an error.

UPDATE

Try

```
(and (arbol-binario? (second a))
     (arbol-binario? (cdr (cdr a))))
```

Comment: I don't know why it evaluates to #t. Any alternative you can suggest to get that #t printed?

Comment: What does "arbol" mean?

Comment: tree. Working with a binary tree here. Should specify it up top.

Comment: On the update. No error nows. However it will always give whatever I put below it. Which is false.

Comment: Well - the main focus was the error :-).  Change `(cdr (cdr a)))` to `(third a)` and examples such as `(arbol-binario? '(42 () ()))` will work.